# Hosting a modal dialog in a ContentControl

Tags: wpf, dialog, hosting

Instead of hosting my modal dialog at the center of my MainWindow, I would like to host it within one of the ContentControls within my MainWindow. Hope someone can advise me how to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean saying "modal dialog"? Give an example.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example on [github](https://github.com/BenjaminGale/ModalContentPresenter) of a custom `FrameworkElement` that allows you to display modal content over the primary content.

The control can be used like this:

```
<c:ModalContentPresenter IsModal="{Binding DialogIsVisible}">
    <TabControl Margin="5">
            <Button Margin="55"
                    Padding="10"
                    Command="{Binding ShowModalContentCommand}">
                This is the primary Content
            </Button>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

    <c:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>
        <Button Margin="75"
                Padding="50"
                Command="{Binding HideModalContentCommand}">
            This is the modal content
        </Button>
    </c:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>

</c:ModalContentPresenter>
```

Features:

- Displays arbitrary content.
- Does not disable the primary content whilst the modal content is being displayed.
- Disables mouse and keyboard access to the primary content whilst the modal content is displayed.
- Is only modal to the content it is covering, not the entire application.
- can be used in an MVVM friendly way by binding to the `IsModal` property.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom `UserControl` built to accomplish this behavior. The article with the code is found [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/), and it can be used like this:

```
<local:PopupPanel 
    Content="{Binding PopupContent}"
    local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=PopupParentPanel}"
    local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}" />
```