# How can my design implement MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an issue trying to understand how to implement the MVVM pattern in my application. It's a small application and I will explain what it does.

My application creates a backup of files. The UI lets the user choose which folder they want to back up and where it should be backed up too. After making their selection they click the "start" button.

This then passes the folder source and folder destination to a class library (called backup.cs) which creates the back ups of all the files inside each folder. During this, a log (Log.cs) is created logging each stage and the state of each file it attempted to back up (complete, failed, other, etc). Now, the log is in memory only.

When the back up is complete I want a window to open (a view) which will display all the logs. It's at this point I can't understand how to use the MVVM pattern.

As it stands today, I pass my log (which holds the data in a hierarchical way) to my MainWindow's constructor and bind to the datacontext, using a treeview in my xaml I get the desired results. However, I now want to use MVVM.

My question is very similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610670/how-to-use-mvvm-when-the-model-is-created-by-view-constructor), as you can see the answer is to pass the log as a paramter to the ViewModel constructor. The issue is, I don't know how to do that and also display a window!

The only way (in my head) I can achieve this is by passing the Log as a parameter to a constructor of my View but this defeats the point of the MVVM. I could pass the parameter to my ViewModel's constructor (which would fit the MVVM pattern) but would that then mean I have to also create an instance of my View from my ViewModel constructor as well? Otherwise all I would do is create my ViewModel but have no way to display the results since the View isn't displayed.

I hope I have explained where I'm struggling clearly, can any one suggest a way forward please?

Comment: How is the log formatted? Could you have it as a collection of entries and databind the view to the collection?

Comment: It is actually a <List>Log , and is hierarchical in formation. The issue isn't getting the data bound, it's how to use the MVVM.. There is no point binding to the ViewModel if the View doesn't show on screen. I don't know how to do both at once (show the View and pass the log to the ViewModel at the same time)

Comment: How have you set your project up for MVVM? How is the Viewmodel set as the datacontext of the view, as a StaticResource in xaml or in the code-behind?

Comment: It sounds like you are having trouble displaying a popup view in an MVVM-compliant manner. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11285526/577417) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you 'll want the viewmodel to accept (and expose through a property) a collection such as a `List<Log>` -- typically this would be an `ObservableCollection<Log>`, but if the operation has already completed there is no real point in going that way. This is what you are describing as a possible solution.

To wire the viewmodel to the view, in essence you need to do this:

```
var viewModel = new LogsViewModel(...);
var view = new LogsView(); // no constructor parameters

view.DataContext = viewModel;
```

And finally you add `view` at some place of the application window's logical tree so that it gets displayed. MVVM frameworks automate this procedure, but you can also do it manually as simply as this.

Your view would then bind to the logs collection to display each log, perhaps using a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- XAML to display each Log does here -->
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: @DaveRook: Not exactly but close. If the view is a permanent part of your window (otherwise InitializeComponent does not come into it) then instead of creating a new one you 'll want to refer to the existing directly using `this.Blah` where `Blah` corresponds to `x:Name="Blah"` for the view in XAML. Otherwise you will create it on the spot as shown, then you 'll have to add it to the window somewhere.

Comment: I really hate exposing model objects to the view, even through properties in a ViewModel, but this is the correct explanation of what's going on.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland: I sometimes do it if the models are dead simple, e.g. a few string/integer properties -- although the default scenario is that the viewmodel exposes a collection of other viewmodels. But in the context of this question that's an implementation detail really.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, if you wanted that LogView being shown based on a button click in you main View.

```
public override void ShowCommandExecute()
{
    var popup = new LogsView                            
    {
       WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
       DataContext = new LogsViewViewModel();
    };
    popup.ShowDialog();
}
```